# Spring How to ignore associate entity when using @ManyToMany JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am facing an issue related to fetch data with associate entity JPA.

Currently, I am using FETCH.LAZY on @ManyToMany
I want to customize query as below:

```
**Repo**
#1
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Query("from User")
List<User> fetchUsers();
#2
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Query("from User u join fetch .userTypes")
List<User> fetchUsersWithType();
```

```
**Entity**
@Setter 
@Getter
@Entity
Class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = UserType.class)
    private Set<UserType> userTypes;
        
}

@Setter 
@Getter
@Entity
Class UserType{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;       
}
```

It's working for the second query
but it throw error **failed to lazily initialize a collection** for my #1 query.

If I set @JsonIgnore on level Enity it will ok and skip userTypes
but it's not what I want

#1 No need userType.
#2 Need userType

Please help advice me, how to achieved this!
THank you!

Comment: Please provide more context (code) where these methods are called and what is done to the returned objects

Comment: @Times I have update my question, plz you helpt to check.